# how do i backup my linuxmint file system and exclude the /media folder?

Tags: files, backup

trying to backup the file system files, but want to exclude /media  folder.

```
dave@``primary ~ $ rsync -a --exclude=' /media/' /media/dave/DEE-NOW/#1AA-linuxmint19/RSYNC_SYS_BACKUP/
```

drwxrwxrwx

and nothing. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you [review the rsync man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) for options. I have had great success using the `-gloptruncv` option to do a dry run and then after trouble shooting any issues run `-gloptrucv`. Remember you are going to need root(sudo) privileges to backup a complete file system.

Comment: @Dave, can you tell, a little bit clearly?

Answer (score 0):

If media is mounted you can use the "-x" or " --one-file-system " of rsync
otherwise try

```
rsync -a --exclude=media /media/dave/DEE-NOW/#1AA-linuxmint19/RSYNC_SYS_BACKUP/
```

Comment: ok, thanks,  but do i have to run the terminal from the root folder to run this command properly? well, i ran the command with -a (copied it from here)...and rsync -x  and still did not work. i have root privileges.  just get drwxrwxrwx.